# Eigenvalues of the Fourier transform on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-analysis

Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $n \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ and $f \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$, the Fourier transform on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ is
$$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}}f(k)e^{-2\pi ikn/N} = N^{-1/2}\langle f, N^{-1/2}e_k\rangle,$$
where $e_k(\cdot) = e^{2\pi i k\cdot/N}$
Apparently, there are only four possible eigenvalues
$$N^{-1/2}, -N^{-1/2}, iN^{-1/2}, -iN^{-1/2}.$$
Seeing that these are the only possible eigenvalues, they look very similar to the $4^{\text{th}}$-roots of unity. But I don't see why.
I try applying this Fourier transform twice, then I get
$$\hat{\hat{f}}(n) = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}}\ \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}}f(m)e^{-2\pi imn/N}e^{-2\pi i kn/N}.$$
It doesn't look simple so I cannot imagine that if I apply the Fourier transform four times I get an identity. Any hints how I can approach this?

Comment: Lots of stuff cancels in the double Fourier transform. Try working it out for small values of $N$, say $N = 2, 3, 4$.